# Android Splash Screen that works with Android 10-11-12 Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have noticed lately that the current splash screen in our xamarin forms apps no longer works in Android 12.
Despite many posts /attempts including this one [Android 12: splash screen is no longer displayed](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/6517)
I still cannot make it work.

Is there a simple solution-snippets that clearly shows how to make the splash screen work in xamarin forms? And should support 10-11-12 - .

Many thanks

Comment: For the android 12, it seems the binding library is must. I also test it in the newest maui, for the android 12 device, the logo will not show either.

Comment: Are we stuck on this one?

Comment: Yes, xamarin does't convert that java library to the nuget package.